# Virus in Safari preventing it from launching?

Tags: safari

I think I got a virus in Safari because I was downloading an app and now Safari will not open. It keeps asking to reopen the last windows closed when opening and whether I click yes or no it doesn't matter. It then crashes and shows a "send a report or ignore" option because Safari will not open.

I already tried restarting my computer and updating Safari. There was a post somewhere else that said something about putting a "com.apple.safari..." item on my desktop out of the Library/Preferences folder, but I do not have that. Must be because of the new update or something.

```
REPORT: Crashed Thread: 16 Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020
External Modification Warnings: Thread creation by external task.
```

Please help me.

Comment: REPORT:

Crashed Thread:        16

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020

External Modification Warnings:
Thread creation by external task.

Comment: Could you disclose what app were you downloading?

Comment: Or if you could publish the whole report on a Dropbox or similar. First line does not help diagnosing the problem.

Comment: If you think you got a Virus try the ClamXav scanner.

Comment: There are too many irrelevant answers, so here you go...(CMD+S) Boot Single-User then **fsck -fy** the issue you are experiencing is pertaining to a data leak.

Answer (score 2):

The folder you mentioned is `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Safari.savedState`

You can find it like this…

- Switch to the Finder & hit <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> to generate a new window.
- Hit <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>-<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> for Go To…
- Copy/paste the following [including the tilde ~ sign]

  `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Safari.savedState`
- Click Go
- Delete the entire contents of that folder; it should be just a few files called `data.data`, `window_1.data` and `windows.plist`

Try launching Safari again.

Comment: I did exactly that and it did not help. I still got this: 

Safari quit unexpectedly.Click Reopen to open the application again. Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple.

This is the beginning of the report if that helps:

Crashed Thread:        16

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020

External Modification Warnings:
Thread creation by external task.

Comment: hmm… then I'm not sure - try going to ~/Library/Safari by the same method. first select all, right click & 'Compress xx Items' so you have a safety-net. Empty the folder [retaining the .zip, of course], try again.

Comment: sorry for negative vote, but the OP clearly says your answer did not work.

Comment: @Buscar웃 last I looked, we were still working on it. -1 would indicate the solution had no hope of working or was simply bad advice, not that it could be tried as a first step.

Comment: As it stands right now your answer did not resolve the issue, so lets see what is to come, and to reverse the Vote. I usually delete my incorrect answer, and come up with a modified version, otherwise as it stands it is misleading to others with same problem. At least I am talking to you, and not just giving a anonymous negative Votes (common practice here :(

Comment: @Buscar웃 if I delete the answer right now then we have no flow of Q/A to reach a solution, only the crash report added to the original question. As SE doesn't timeline particularly well, the intermediate solution is to leave things as they are until more info is gathered.

Answer (score 1):

You might be victim of Genieo/InstallMac malware.

Here are the details to remove the malware: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203987

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6731664

**Remove Genieo, also known as InstallMac:**

First follow these steps to stop the Genieo or InstallMac processes, if they're running. Be particularly careful to restart your Mac when instructed.

1. Open Activity Monitor. You can use Spotlight (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>) and type in Activity Monitor, then click on it to open it.
2. In the Activity Monitor window, click the CPU tab, then click Process Name at the top of that column to sort the list alphabetically.
3. Look for the process "Genieo". Select it, then click the Force Quit button (x) on the toolbar at the top of the window
4. Look for the process "InstallMac". Select it, then click the Force Quit button.
5. Quit Activity Monitor.
6. From the Finder, choose Go → Go to Folder.
7. Type `/private/etc/launchd.conf` in the text field, then press Return.
8. If the file is on your Mac, a window opens with the file you searched for already selected. Drag the file to the Trash.

Restart your Mac, then continue to the next steps, below.

Remove the files related to Genieo:

1. Select each item in the list below, starting with /Applications/Genieo.
2. Choose Edit → Copy.
3. From the Finder, choose Go → Go to Folder.
4. Choose Edit → Paste to paste the line you copied into the text field, then press Return.
5. If the file is on your Mac, a window opens with the file you searched for already selected. Drag the file to the Trash.

Repeat the steps above for each item in the following list. If you get a message that the folder can't be found, continue to the next item in the list.

`/Applications/Genieo
/Applications/InstallMac
/Applications/Uninstall Genieo
/Applications/Uninstall IM Completer.app
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.genieo.completer.download.plist
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.genieo.completer.update.plist
/Library/LaunchAgents/com.genieoinnovation.macextension.plist
/Library/LaunchAgents/com.genieoinnovation.macextension.client.plist
/Library/LaunchAgents/com.genieo.engine.plist
/Library/LaunchAgents/com.genieo.completer.update.plist
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.genieo.completer.ltvbit.plist
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.genieoinnovation.macextension.client.plist
/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.genieoinnovation.macextension.client
/usr/lib/libgenkit.dylib
/usr/lib/libgenkitsa.dylib
/usr/lib/libimckit.dylib
/usr/lib/libimckitsa.dylib
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.genieo.global.settings.plist
~/Library/SavedState/com.genieo.RemoveGenieoMac.savedState`

Now do the same for each folder in the following list. When these folders open, no file will be selected. Instead, select all items (Command-A) in the folder and drag them all to the Trash.

`~/Library/Application Support/Genieo/
~/Library/Application Support/com.genieoinnovation.Installer/
~/Library/Saved Application State/com.genieo.RemoveGenieoMac.savedState/`

Restart your Mac, then continue to the next steps below.

1. From the Finder, choose Go → Go to Folder.
2. Type `/Library/Frameworks/GenieoExtra.framework` in the text field, then press Return.
3. If the file is on your Mac, a window opens with the file you searched for already selected. Drag the file to the Trash.

Restart your Mac, then choose Finder → Empty Trash to permanently remove the files.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Start in Safe Mode (holding the Shift key), does Safari open?
Then restart normally.